# Computing the partition funciton of 2 identical particles in a harmonic oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, partition-function

Say I have two identical (fermionic) non-interacting particles in a 1D harmonic oscillator. I would like to compute the entropy of the system as the temperature $T$ varies, for which I need the partition function of this system, then I would calculate the entropy like

$$
F = -k_B T \log(Z) \Longrightarrow S = -\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}
$$

However I am stuck when trying to compute $Z$, can anyone help?

**My attempt**

The particles are non-interacting, therefore the energy of the system is given by $E_{n, m} = E_n + E_m= \hbar \omega(1+n+m)$ so to compute the (canonical) partition function we need to compute

$$
Z = \sum_{n, m}e^{-\beta E_{n, m}} = e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}\sum_{n, m}\Big(e^{-\beta\hbar \omega}\Big)^n\Big(e^{-\beta\hbar \omega}\Big)^m = e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}\sum_n\Big(e^{-\beta\hbar \omega}\Big)^n\Big(e^{-\beta\hbar \omega}\Big)^n + e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}\sum_{n<m}\Big(e^{-\beta\hbar \omega}\Big)^n\Big(e^{-\beta\hbar \omega}\Big)^m = \frac{e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}}{1-e^{-2\beta \hbar \omega}} + \sum_{n<m}\Big(e^{-\beta\hbar \omega}\Big)^n\Big(e^{-\beta\hbar \omega}\Big)^m
$$

at this point I am stuck. How can I compute the second part of $Z$?

Comment: If you must evaluate $Z$ without noting it's the square of the one-particle case, the $n<m$ double sum you're stuck on is$$\sum_ne^{-n\beta\hbar\omega}\sum_{m\ge n+1}e^{-m\beta\hbar\omega},$$which is easily rewritten (by evaluating the inner sum) as a geometric series.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294919/n-copies-of-1d-bosonic-harmonic-oscillator-partition-function), check also the links to the papers therein.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/703139/derivation-of-partition-function-for-n-identical-quantum-harmonic-oscillators/703140#703140).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Bosonic statistics, we write:

$$ Z=\sum_{n=m} e^{-\beta E_{n,n}}+ \frac12 \sum_{n\neq m} e^{-\beta E_{n,m}}  = \frac12 \sum_{n=m} e^{-\beta E_{n,n}}+ \frac12 \sum_{n, m} e^{-\beta E_{n,m}} $$

The second sum is unconstrained now.